# Code for Multivariate Random Forest in Python/R?

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, random-forest

I am trying to code multivariate (or Multi output dx input features and dy outputs) Random Forest Regressor algorithm for a project, i.e. the algorithm can be used to predict more than one dependent variables using same features and training the model only once to account for correlation between the response variables. Does anyone know or have an already coded algorithm in R or python that I can use as a reference?

I know that Sklearn Randomforest can be applied in Multivariate settings. And there is a Package in R called Mutlivariate Random Forest for such use. But, I need an amateur level from scratch implementation that I can understand and learn from about how to code GINI gain function and prediction function for the algorithm.

I tried scouting the Github, but haven't found anything useful yet.

Thank you in advance to whoever is helping.

Comment: If your variables have few levels and performance is not so critical, you could create a variable that maps each combination of variables to one new category, and fit a regular classifier on that.

Comment: The only one I know is "oblique trees".  [link](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#Oblique_Tree) [link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6f1d/e5c5e624c003d0697eb38f11ec2f3aeffe5a.pdf)